# Remove or Delete Hidden Content type in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

How Remove or delete the created content type belong in _Hidden Group in sharepoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Get-PnPContentType|? { $_.Group -eq '_Hidden' }` to get content types belong in "_Hidden" group like the below:
[image]

Then use [Remove-PnPContentType](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnpcontenttype?view=sharepoint-ps) to remove the content types that you want to remove or delete.

Comment: Thank you Kally, and how can i connect my sharepoint site in Sharepoint management Shell without an access in company-admin@sharepoint.com, and my only access is Site Collection Admin in 1 site only thanks.

Comment: In my test, you can delete the content type with only site collection administrator permissions using pnp powershell, you could have a try.

Comment: It's working thanks a lot kally ^_^  have a great day

Comment: I am glad to help you, please remember to accept my reply as answer.:)